# JPA and EJB - OneToMany problem

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0

I try to build simple Java EE application that uses JPA + EJB3 and Stripes.
It's a little address book. I'm using 2 JPA entities, Person and Email. Every person can have more emails, but each email can only belong to one person. My entities looks like this (with default setters and getters):

Person.java:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy = "person")
    private Collection<Email> emails; ... }
```

Email.java:

```
@Entity
public class Email implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String note;
    private String address;
    @ManyToOne
    private Person person; ... }
```

But when I try to show the list of every person and all their emails, I can't get emails to show. This is how I'm trying to print them:

```
<c:forEach items="${actionBean.people}" var="person">
  <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${person.name}"/></td>
    <td>
      <c:forEach items="${person.email}" var="email">
          <c:out value="${email.address}"/><c:out value="${email.note}"/>
      </c:forEach>
    </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Any idea, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `Person` class have a `getEmail()` method or a `getEmails()` method?  Given the variable name of `emails` I would expect a `Person.getEmails()` given the attribute name, but your JSTL is looking for `getEmail()`.

If that's not the problem, I believe you might need to add a `@JoinColumn` annotation to your `Email` class, and add a column to the email table that refers back to the person id.  This is how I've done all my ManyToOne annotations.  An example ManyToOne can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne).